# Neo4J CSV into Props

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using cypher and the neo4j browser to create nodes from csv input.

I want to read in each row of my csv file with headers and then create a node with that row as properties.

MY current code is:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM '<yourFilePath>' AS ROW
WITH ROW 
CREATE (n:node $ROW)
```

This throws an error saying parameter missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM '<yourFilePath>' AS row
CREATE (n:node)
SET n+= row
```

Answer (score 0):

In Cypher, variables that start with "$" must be passed to the query as [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/). Your Cypher code is locally binding values to the `ROW` variable (and not passing a parameter), so change `$ROW` to `ROW`.

In addition, if you want to make sure that you do not generate duplicate nodes, you should consider using [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) instead of `CREATE`. But before you do so, you must carefully read the documentation on `MERGE` to understand how to use it properly.